# Swift limit number of rows in section & extend limit once bottom reached

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

**Problem:**

I would like to limit the amount of cells shown. For example, 100.
Once the tableView has reached the bottom I would like to extend that limit further since the data is already there, I do not need an activity loader.

I simply would like to tableView refresh and exceed the minimum of 100 in a smooth manner

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
        if(delegate.groupedSessions[section].count > 100){
            return 100
        }else{
            return delegate.groupedSessions[section].count
        }
      
    }
```

**Pseudocode:**

(If scrolled to bottom or indexPath.row >= 100)

Exceed numberOfRowsInSection limit to 200 and so on.

Comment: why you need this logic even? you think that tableview loads all 100 rows one time? if you are thinking, you are wrong. Tableview only loads data for the number of rows which are visible and re-use cells to display when scrolling is done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let increment = 100
var limit == 100

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Not sure how your code is set up or what "delegate" is but I'm assuming that's your model that holds the data
    if limit < delegate.groupedSessions[section].count {
        return limit
    } else {
        return delegate.groupedSessions[section].count
    }
}

// This is a Delegate Method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard indexPath.row == limit - 1 else { return }
        
    limit += increment
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I'm also not sure what you're trying to achieve. Even if you do this, the tableview would just keep scrolling smoothly like the limits weren't even there. But you asked, so.